# Is it advisable to redirect all similar websites to a single website now ? (Can It give a positive result in SEO rank)

Tags: seo, google, 301-redirect, search-results

Is it safe to redirect other similar domains I own to a my brand website now ? can it have a positive or negative impact on the ranking. 
I understand that, Google handles the 301 redirection differently now.

Example, I own the following websites...

1. blackshoes.com
2. premiumblackshoes.com
3. mybrand-shoes.com

Now, I want to retain only one domain which is mybrand-shoes.com and I want to redirect blackshoes.com & premiumblackshoes.com to mybrand-shoes.com.

I currently use and built a brand around the domain name,  mybrand-shoes.com. Site 1 and 2 has lots of back links which were built using grayhat technique. If I redirect site 1 and 2, then mybrand-shoes.com might get lots of backlink.

All the above domains are 8 years old. I am sure, someone might have done similar case study here.

Someone please help me.

Answer (score 1):

> which were built using grayhat technique

Oh, this could be hazardous for your primarily brand site... You would run into risc of building of private blog network and your grayhat backlinks could do the bad job for your white brand website.

If i would be on your place, i would not link or redirect both grayhat-ed domains to the main one. Not forever, but for some time.

In the meanwhile i would develop the two grayhated domains to content projects (blog/magazin/guide) and develop them in this direction as long as they begin to get good backlinks.

Let them earn good backlinks for a half of a year and them link them to the main brand domain.